# Generate a random unique character?

Tags: sql-server

For the purpose of my application, I need to identify certain records by using a **single** CHAR character for each record. I want to be able to automatically generate a unique character whenever a new record is added, kinda like a normal int type auto-increment id. Is there a way to do that? What character gets picked doesn't matter to me, it can be random.

Note: the limit doesn't matter to me, the table is pretty small, it certainly wont be more than 200 records.

Comment: A single Varchar for each record, you will run out of characters after a few hundred records

Comment: That seems pretty limiting. You have 26 characters (case insensitive), and ten more for numbers, … even if you opened yourself up to all special and control characters, you'd have at most 250 or so.

Comment: Right, I forgot to mention that, the table is very small, so I wont go over that limit. I'm just _very_ lazy. :)

Comment: ...a _single varchar_...

Comment: @KekuSemau ... yes? Care to elaborate?

Comment: `varchar` type fields consist of a _var_ -iable number of _chars_. In your question varying in length anywhere between one and one. The juxtaposition of two directly contradicting words struck me with a certain irony. (You want char(1) or nchar(1), not varchar).

Comment: @KekuSemau Right, my mistake. It's hard for me to keep up with all those different char types, so I'm glad for the clarification. I changed it, thanks.

Comment: If you have control of the application and are not constrained, I have to say it is an extremely bad idea to generate a key in such a manner! The entire reason for auto incremented columns is to handle the keys like this.  You say it will be a small table but what if the records ever exceeds the values will you reset the key and reuse.  Or what if you delete will the key be reused.  You have a major uniqueness and reuse issue with a design like this.  if you are absolutely forced to use a char you have other issues to consider such as DB encoding, unicode non unicode

Comment: @Matt I have full control over the table. The records will never exceed the limit because I simply don't need any more records. It is just a "system" table of sorts, that grabs certain settings and is never modified. The only time it gets modified is maybe when I update the application and add two or three additional records to the table, but that's it. For the purpose of the application, it's just used to read data out, never to write or modify its contents.

Comment: @noClue then I would still stick with the integer not a character, I see no benefit of using a character in that case.  If you persist to use a character than the primary key should still be an integer like a couple examples below and then you could use a computed column or second key to make the readable character

Comment: @Matt That's great, but that rising number wont help me much when it goes into the double digits. There's a reason why I want a single character to identify a record, and unless I tell you exactly what the application is, which I wont do, you wont understand. Just trust me when I say I got good reasons to do it the way I do it.

Comment: @noClue I bet I would still challenge the reasons but I will bite. so you don't care if something is human readable or not  e.g. is a-zA-Z0-9 the desired characters or is the full ASCII table fair game?

Comment: @noClue also you keep saying very small number of rows.  Can you guarantee less than 19? 26? 52? 62?

Comment: @Matt Don't get me wrong, I'm not implying that my way is the only way to the solution of my specific problem, it's just something I prefer because it makes the integration into my application a lot easier. ASCII is fair game and the table wont _ever_ get bigger than 80 rows, guaranteed.

Comment: @noClue I guess I would go with Ryan's answer but start identity at 33 like paparazzo states that will give you 222 values. If 62 or less I have other ideas, but at 80 you will exceed a-Z0-9.  You will still maintain an auto incremented Identity on the table and that can be used for references etc.  But it will give you a single char for your situation.  Also means it will be unique without having to manage it.

Comment: @noClue and this is a bit pesky but I would make your data type for the int identity column TINYINT that way you will get an error if you should ever exceed the solution.  Plus uses less storage space...

Comment: Just another sidenote: like [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106209/unexpected-gaps-in-identity-column), identity columns may skip numbers in some cases, they do not guarantee to be gapless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe just use a regular IDENTITY field, and then add a computed column that calculates your character off the IDENTITY?

That will give you several hundred rows.  Enough for your requirement.

```
declare @testTable as TABLE
(
    id int identity(65,1)
    , myData varchar(100)
    , idChar as char(id)
)

insert into @testTable (myData)
Values ('January'), ('February'), ('March'), ('April'), ('May'), ('June'), ('July'), ('August'), ('September'), ('October'), ('November'), ('December')
,('January'), ('February'), ('March'), ('April'), ('May'), ('June'), ('July'), ('August'), ('September'), ('October'), ('November'), ('December')
,('January'), ('February'), ('March'), ('April'), ('May'), ('June'), ('July'), ('August'), ('September'), ('October'), ('November'), ('December')
,('January'), ('February'), ('March'), ('April'), ('May'), ('June'), ('July'), ('August'), ('September'), ('October'), ('November'), ('December')
,('January'), ('February'), ('March'), ('April'), ('May'), ('June'), ('July'), ('August'), ('September'), ('October'), ('November'), ('December')
,('January'), ('February'), ('March'), ('April'), ('May'), ('June'), ('July'), ('August'), ('September'), ('October'), ('November'), ('December')


select * from @testable
```

Results in :

```
id          myData                      idChar
----------- --------------------------- ------
65          January                     A
66          February                    B
67          March                       C
68          April                       D
69          May                         E
70          June                        F
71          July                        G
72          August                      H
73          September                   I
74          October                     J
75          November                    K
```

Answer (score 2):

Create an identity column that starts on 33 (0-32 are control characters).

Create a computed column with a formula of `char(iden)`.

I was working on this before the other answer was present.

Comment: But you posted this two minutes after the other answer?

Comment: Doesn't really matter, the other guy still beat you to the punch. :)